# How to loop function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have same function that I want to make it based on user input ,

```
    for(var u = 1; u <= tmp; u++){            
      $('#photo_'+u).change(function(){
            $('#src_'+u).val($(this).val());
      });
```

Caption: tmp is user input

I try jshint in jsfiddle showing error : "Don't make function withit loop"

how to make that function loop

My question is based in this Link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447811/paste-input-type-file-value-to-input-type-text)

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: no need for a loop you have to use class instead of using elemant ID.. just check the answer

Comment: javascript ? it is jquery

Comment: just `$('#photo_'+u).change(function() {            $('#src_'+u).val($(this).val());
});` is sufficient enough

Answer (score 2):

change id and use class:

```
 $('.photo').change(function(){
     $(this).find('.src').val($(this).val());
 });
```

change **#photo_...** and **#src_...** to class.

- $(this) will to point to current **.photo** element

no need for a loop in this case...

Comment: but i need loop, for each content

Comment: this will apply the function to all elements without loop..

Comment: please provide the html content in your page

Answer (score 2):

```
var functionStr="";   
     for(var u=1;u<=tmp;u++){    
     if(u==tmp)   
     {
        functionStr=functionStr+"#photo_"+u; 
     }  
     else  
     {   
        functionStr=functionStr+"#photo_"+u+",";       
     }


     $(functionStr).change(function(){

           $('#src_'+u).val($(this).val());

    });
```